# How to get id of a specific tree node when I click on them and then pass that data into my variable

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I am new to Quasar and Vue. Could someone explain to me how to solve my task?

Briefly about the task:

(1) I have a q-tree element which represents the folder structure at the left side of a screen [ref.1]

(2) Here is a folder structure [ref.2]

(3) When the user clicks on any element in this folder structure, then he will see a new component on the right side with all children elements of clicked one in a grid layout.

This is what do I have now.

[ref.1] treeComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <q-tree
    :nodes="documents"
    @click="getId"
    node-key="id" >
  </q-tree>
</template>

<script>
var documents = require('./documents')
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      selectedDoc: x,
      documents: documents
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getId: function () {
      const x = this.getNodeByKey('id')
      consol.log(x)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[ref.2] documents.js

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    id: '1',
    label: 'My Documents',
    icon: 'folder',
    children: [
      {
        id: '01',
        label: 'Dir 1',
        children: [
          { id: '0001', label: 'Doc 1'},
          { id: '0002', label: 'Doc 2'}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        label: 'Dir 2',
        children: [
          { id: '0003', label: 'Doc 3'},
          { id: '0004', label: 'Doc 4'}
        ]
      },
      {
        id: '103',
        label: 'Dir 3',
        children: [
          { id: '0005', label: 'Doc 5'},
          { id: '0006', label: 'Doc 6'},
          { id: '0007', label: 'Doc 7'}
        ]
      }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: could you get back the node by this statement `const x = this.getNodeByKey('id')`?

Comment: Nah, it is not working.

Comment: add this `selected.sync="selectedDoc"` to your template and in your data object add `selectedDoc:null`

Comment: Nope, still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace id by key.after this add this handler for each node

```
handler: (node) => this.onclick(node)
```

then add this method in methods

```
onclick(node) {
  alert(node.key)
},
```

this will display id of perticular node

Answer (score 0):

So, the main problem was related to not good enough acquainted with Quasar framework.
Here is my answer to this question:

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click = "showNodeSelected">showClickedNode</button>
  <q-tree
    :nodes = "documents"
    :selected.sync = "selected"
    node-key="id"
  />
</template>

<script>
var documents = require('./documents')
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      selected: null,
      documents: documents
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showNodeSelected: function () {
      console.log(this.selected)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```